# Where and how to download Spring jars?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar, dependencies

Must I use maven to get the spring dependency? http://spring.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can download Spring Jars from [here](https://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/).

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not necessary. 
Just check this [site](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/3.2.4.RELEASE) and download the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Few points I would like to make here

1. Why you do not want to use maven or any other project management tool?
2. What these tools does is download relevant dependencies so that you do not have to configure those manually which is a real pain
3. If you want to get the jar you can get that in the .m2 repository on your user home once maven downloads it